# Entity Framework - Using GUID as condition

Tags: .net, entity-framework

How can I use this sample [Inheritance and Associations with Entity Framework](http://mosesofegypt.net/post/Inheritance-and-Associations-with-Entity-Framework-Part-1.aspx)  but using a data type GUID as Condition?

In this sample, I only use Strings and Integers as Condition.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,  so long as the GUID is not also a foreign key. Any scalar type is allowed, and GUIDs are scalar, but it is a limitation of the currently shipping version of the Entity Framework that you cannot use a foreign key value as a subtype discriminator field.

Comment: False premise. Integers and GUIDs are treated exactly the same in this respect.

Comment: I tried, but not worked. Message:
Error 2016: Condition can not be specified on member PersonCategory of type Edm.Guid

Comment: Then it is probably a navigational property. Like I said, you cannot do that.